# measure elapsed time in c++ multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

I have a AI Minimax code for the game of checkers in C++. In this, the main program calls the function that I have written in a new thread while it sleeps for 5 secs after which it returns to main program

```
int flag = 0 ;
void execute(){
    hThread = ( HANDLE ) _beginthread( myfunction ) ;
    sleep( 5000 );

    if(flag == 1) // Do some work 
}


Outputval myfunction(...) {

   clock_t start = clock() ;
   while( double(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC < 4 ) {   //CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000

      //DO SOME WORK

   }
   flag = 1;
   return somevalue ;

}
```

My problem is that although the work done in my function require approximately 3-4 sec , yet the time elapsed that is calculated after every iteration is that of order 0-1 sec. So the loop in myfunction keeps on running even if 4 secs has passed and the flag is not set
I have also used time() function - it gives same problem.

Comment: Does **void execute** without the () work?  What is CLOCKS_PER_SEC defined as?  Would it be easier to use time_t which returns the time in seconds?

Comment: I don't think that your design is very good. There is no guarantee that myfunction() will finish its work before the sleep on the main thread terminates. What is it you are trying to achieve anyway? Is there a real reason for spawning a new thread to perform the work? It would make sense if your main thread was busy doing something else, but as it stands, it's not really doing anything other than wait. Besides, you should try using semaphores or mutexes instead of  flags as they are more secure and timeout can be inherent in the wait functions.

Comment: That's the reason I have used the loop. I have to ensure in myfunction() that it returns before sleep on main thread terminates. The execute function execute I can't change as it has come from some other team and has to be used as it is.The only thing I can modify is myfunction().

Comment: @user3289221 I'm sorry, but without changing the execute() function, there is no way to absolutely guarantee that you finish execution before the 5 second timeout elapses. Here's an example:  Say the first iteration of the loop in myfunction() took 3.5 seconds. when the while is checked, it still is smaller than 4 thus the loop is executed again. This time it takes only 2.5 (yay!) seconds. A quick calculation in your head will show that this is a total of 6 seconds therefore more than the 5 seconds waited by the main thread. (surprisingly the flag may still be 1 when the main thread checks)

Comment: Thanks . I just came to the same conclusion as yours. Therefore, I used (elasped time) < 1.2 condition for good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but a "caution":

Assuming your variable *flag* is global and visible in both threads. Since at least one access is not atomic (C++11) or *flag* is not *volatile* (C++03), your code contains a "data race", and this will trigger "undefined behavior". Undefined behavior opens a wide range of optimization opportunities for the compiler:

The compiler will optimize your code as follows:

starting with:

```
int flag = 0 ;
void execute{
    hThread = ( HANDLE ) _beginthread( myfunction ) ;
    sleep( 5000 );

    if(flag == 1) // Do some work 
}
```

it may eventually create this code:

```
constexpr int flag = 0 ;
void execute{
    hThread = ( HANDLE ) _beginthread( myfunction ) ;
    sleep( 5000 );

    if(0) {}// Never do anything
}
```

Your code has other issues as well. I suggest a complete redesign.